# What's wrong in this sql statement?

Tags: sql

What's wrong in this sql statements ?

```
insert into employee values(a-101,suman,20-convent-road,03/02/76,05/05/03,20000);  

insert into employee values(a-101,suman,20_convent_road,03/02/76,05/05/03,20000);
```

Comment: It's showing  wrong address

Comment: did you get any error message?

Comment: `03/02/76` is an arithmetic expression, `20_ convent_road` is an invalid name; use quotations: `'20-convent-road'`

Comment: Error message -  column not allowed here , invalid character

Answer (score 2):

You need:

- single quotes around strings
- dates in a standard format
- a list of columns for the `insert`

Something like this:

```
insert into employee(col1, col2, . . . )  -- whatever the columns are
    values('a-101', 'suman', '20-convent-road',
           '1976-03-02', '2003-05-05', 20000
          );
```

Comment: unless `a -101` is a numeric operation and `suman` is a variable

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . That would be possible in a database that supports such constants.  Not all do.  (And of course the same would apply to `a`, `convent`, and `road`).   For that matter, the OP could intend `03/02/76` as an arithmetic expression.  But I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

insert into employee values('a-101','suman','20-convent-road','03/02/76','05/05/03',20000);

**Try to keep the string and date values in single code.May be it help you**